# SWRevealViewController add gesture to a presented viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealViewController in my project, it is working perfectly, the TableView has 6 options, each pressing leads to a different ViewController.

The problem comes when I instantiate another ViewController manually (called viewControllerModelos), this viewcontroller is not linked to a side menu option, but I do need that from that viewcontroller it can also be displayed.

I present the ViewController instantiated correctly, but the Side Menu does not appear when sliding, although I have the gesture added in that ViewController

Could someone tell me the way please?

The code below is in a viewcontroller in which the side menu is shown

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewControllerModelos = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewControllerModelos") as! VC_catalogo_modelos
        self.present(viewControllerModelos, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The code below is that of the instantiated viewcontroller

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class VC_catalogo_modelos: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if revealViewController() != nil {
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: you are pushing viewControllerModelos controller from sidebar? or from someWhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are just presenting VC_catalogo_modelos you are not settings root to revealViewController due to this reason nothing is working in your case

```
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let sw = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sw") as! SWRevealViewController // can place sw with revealViewCOntroller identifier
            self.view.window?.rootViewController = sw
            let viewControllerModelos = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewControllerModelos") as! VC_catalogo_modelos
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewControllerModelos!) // using navigationController can help in future if there are other controller on action 
            navigationController.navigationBar.isHidden=false // unhide if you need navigationController bar
            navigationController.setNavigationTints()

             sw.setFront(navigationController, animated: true)
            //pushFrontViewController(navigationController, animated: true) Use only if you require a push otherwise setFront
```

Answer (score 1):

perfect! Thank you so much for your help, this worked for me.

```
    let sw  = revealViewController()
    // can place sw with revealViewCOntroller identifier
    self.view.window?.rootViewController = sw
    let viewControllerModelos = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewControllerModelos") as! VC_catalogo_modelos
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewControllerModelos)
    navigationController.navigationBar.isHidden=false
    navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    sw!.setFront(navigationController, animated: true)
```